# Convert float32 bits os pfrecision to float16 bits of presicion

Tags: java

Hi i want to compare the results of the program with an analisis i made about the binaries; but for this, i need floats to be of 16 instead of 32 bits; is there a function that make this convertion?

The program is this:

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    float _16 DeltaTime=0.09375;
    float _16 time = 0.0f;
    float _16 Vx = 92.25f;
    float _16 v=0;
    float _16 a=0.625f;
    float _16 x=0.0f;
    float _16 xLimite = 6808.05f;
    int _16 i=0;

    while(x<=xLimite){
      time=time+DeltaTime;
      v=(a*time);
      x=((v*v))/(2*a);
      i++;
      if(v>=Vx){
        System.out.println("In the point");
        break;
      }
    }

  }
}
```

I make comparisons in paper but i also want to see it in a program, is possible to use just 16 bits in float? no matters the language.

Comment: There are going to be a number of C programmers and C++ programmers looking at that code and asking themselves, "Why am I here?" so I removed the tags. If you truly don't care about the language, tag as `language-agnostic`. Architecture and bit don't seem all that useful so I clipped them as well.

Comment: C and C++ do not have a `half` datatype out of the box. My Java's 20-years stale and at my peak wasn't all that good so I can't answer whether or not Java has a `half`.

Comment: A 16-bit floating point number only has about 3 digits of precision.  0.09375 is not representable - the nearest would be 0.0938 (0x2E00).  6808.05 is also not representable and would be 6808.0 (0x6EA6).  The next largest half-precision float would be 6812, so the fact that you're concerned about that `0.05` at the end seems to suggest that half-precision floating point is not suitable for this application.

Answer (score 0):

In OpenCL there is half data type. You have to have support for it, namely cl_khr_fp16 extension must be present, see https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/2.2/docs/man/html/halfDataType.html

For conversion you can then use the following functions https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/vectorDataLoadandStoreFunctions.html